# Add annotation between line gap in plotly

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, plotly, plotly-python

I have a graph like this:
[image]

Instead of the days being on top of the `symbol`, I was wondering if there is a way I can add this annotation between the lines? From one dot to another. I apologize if in case, this is a possible duplicate.

This is my expected output:
[image]

This is my current code for the annotation:

```py
    fig.add_annotation(
        go.layout.Annotation(
            x=row["order_date"],
            y=row["sales"],
            text=f"{row['time_diff']} days",
            showarrow=False,
            align='center',
            yanchor='auto',
            yshift=10,
            textangle=-0
        )
```

Any suggestions on how can I do this?

Comment: I added an expected output, hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is create a new dataframe for your annotations by ordering your original `df` by the `order_date`, then take the average datetime and average sales between consecutive rows to determine where to place the annotations. To obtain the text, you can take the difference in time between consecutive orders.

Your dataframe for annotations would look something like this:

```
  time_diff  sales          order_date
0    5 days    5.0 2019-08-27 12:00:00
1   11 days    5.0 2019-09-04 12:00:00
2    0 days    7.5 2019-09-10 00:00:00
3    0 days   15.0 2019-09-10 00:00:00
4    5 days   20.0 2019-09-12 12:00:00
5    0 days   17.5 2019-09-15 00:00:00
6  139 days   15.0 2019-11-23 12:00:00
7       NaT    NaN                 NaT
```

And here is a figure I made using some sample data similar to yours:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

## create sample data and figure similar to yours
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'order_date': ['2019-08-25 00:00:00','2019-08-30','2019-09-10','2019-09-10','2019-09-10','2019-09-15','2019-09-15','2020-02-01'],
    'sales': [5,5,5,10,20,20,15,15],
})
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])

fig = px.line(df, x='order_date', y='sales', markers=True, )
fig.update_traces(marker_color='blue', line_color='darkgrey')

## between consecutive points:
## get the difference in time, and the average sales
df_diff = pd.DataFrame({
    'time_diff': df['order_date'].diff(),
    'sales': (df['sales'] + df['sales'].shift(-1)) / 2,
})

df_diff['order_date'] = df['order_date'] + (df_diff['time_diff'] / 2).shift(-1)
df_diff['time_diff'] = df_diff['time_diff'].shift(-1)

y_axis_range = 1.25*(df.sales.max() - df.sales.min())

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df_diff["order_date"],
        y=df_diff["sales"] + 0.01*y_axis_range,
        text=df_diff["time_diff"].astype(str),
        mode='text',
        showlegend=False,
    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: hey! I have a slight error in this when I try to add `content` column as color and symbol for this. `content` basically has info on what happened to the delivery, sometimes it can be Nan. But when I add it, the colors and symbol don't show up and the graph becomes unconnected

Comment: maybe you can drop any rows where the `content` column is `NaN`? or would you be losing important information?

Comment: I tried doing that, somehow it still doesn't join, because I think it is plotting them as different traces, in scatter it connects the dots by a line

Comment: @IreneHawkins is it possible you could ask this as a separate question? if you can include a sample of your dataframe (with the `content` column) by copying and pasting the output from `df.head(10).to_dict()` in your question, that would be really helpful so I can reproduce the behavior you're seeing – thank you!

Comment: Yes!! i have added the issue as a new question over here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76093399/line-chart-giving-different-traces-for-color-parameter, thank you so much for helping me figure this out!!