# Line chart giving different traces for color parameter

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a df in this form:

```
{'content': {175: nan,
  176: nan,
  177: 'Address not Found',
  178: 'Delivery delayed-transport issues',
  179: nan,
  180: 'Parcel returned',
  181: 'Parcel lost in mail',
  182: 'Parcel received',
  183: 'Return requested',
  184: 'Repeat order placed},
 'sales': {175: 7.0,
  176: 7.0,
  177: 9.0,
  178: 13.0,
  179: 11.0,
  180: 9.0,
  181: 19.0,
  182: 14.0,
  183: 9.0,
  184: 9.0},
 'order_date': {175: Timestamp('2019-08-28 16:30:00'),
  176: Timestamp('2019-08-30 11:55:53'),
  177: Timestamp('2019-09-06 14:51:14'),
  178: Timestamp('2019-09-06 15:03:22'),
  179: Timestamp('2019-09-06 15:46:11'),
  180: Timestamp('2019-09-06 16:08:03'),
  181: Timestamp('2019-09-06 17:13:01'),
  182: Timestamp('2019-09-16 21:38:29'),
  183: Timestamp('2019-09-25 12:35:29'),
  184: Timestamp('2019-09-25 22:22:51')}}
```

This is in reference to this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76059875/add-annotation-between-line-gap-in-plotly)

I want to plot a line chart with `color` and`symbol` as the content column. However, when I do this:

```py
fig = px.line(df, x='order_date', y='sales',color='content',symbol='content', color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Pastel,
              markers=True, line_shape='hvh')
```

I am getting separate lines for the content, and some of them are just dots in the graph: not being connected, I am not sure why this happens. I tried replacing the `Nan` values with `None`, and the error still remains.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the reason the lines aren't connected is because when you specify `color` or `symbol` using plotly express, this will cause plotly to separate the data into different traces. and these traces won't have any connection with each other. i think i have an idea for a possible workaround, and will post if i figure something out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `px.line` in plotly express, specifying a `color` or `symbol` will cause plotly to split up your data by each unique color (or symbol), and plot these as separate traces. Lines are only drawn between traces with the same color.

Imagine your data looks like `{'time': [1,2,3,4,5], 'values':[10,20,30,40,50], 'color': [a,b,c,a,b]}`. When you define `fig = px.line(df, x='time', y='values', color='color'`, plotly will draw a line from point a to point a, point b to point b, and render point c as a single point. What you want instead is a single line connecting all of your points in order by `time`.

One possible workaround would be to create `fig1` where we use px.line to draw only the line with no markers. Then create `fig2` where we use px.scatter to draw only the markers (with the colors and symbols). Then combine the data from both figures together into `fig3`.

Here is an example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

Timestamp = pd.Timestamp
nan = float("nan")

data = {'content': {175: nan,
  176: nan,
  177: 'Address not Found',
  178: 'Delivery delayed-transport issues',
  179: nan,
  180: 'Parcel returned',
  181: 'Parcel lost in mail',
  182: 'Parcel received',
  183: 'Return requested',
  184: 'Repeat order placed'},
 'sales': {175: 7.0,
  176: 7.0,
  177: 9.0,
  178: 13.0,
  179: 11.0,
  180: 9.0,
  181: 19.0,
  182: 14.0,
  183: 9.0,
  184: 9.0},
 'order_date': {175: Timestamp('2019-08-28 16:30:00'),
  176: Timestamp('2019-08-30 11:55:53'),
  177: Timestamp('2019-09-06 14:51:14'),
  178: Timestamp('2019-09-06 15:03:22'),
  179: Timestamp('2019-09-06 15:46:11'),
  180: Timestamp('2019-09-06 16:08:03'),
  181: Timestamp('2019-09-06 17:13:01'),
  182: Timestamp('2019-09-16 21:38:29'),
  183: Timestamp('2019-09-25 12:35:29'),
  184: Timestamp('2019-09-25 22:22:51')}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.sort_values(by='order_date') 

fig1 = px.line(df, x='order_date', y='sales').update_traces(line_color='lightgrey')
fig2 = px.scatter(df, x='order_date', y='sales',color='content',symbol='content', color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Pastel)
fig3 = go.Figure(data=fig1.data + fig2.data)
fig3.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Will this work with the in-line annotations code combined?

Comment: @IreneHawkins it should, provided that you add the annotations separately